Force Spark to use specific Shuffle Handle
Spark has (from what I see) three types of ShuffleHandle Class, SerializedShuffleHandle, BypassMergeSortShuffleHandle, BaseShuffleHandle.
I want to force Spark to use BaseShuffleHandle, preventing him from using BypassMergeSortShuffleHandle is easy using bypassMergeThreshold.
Preventing him from using SerializedShuffleHandle it's a different story.
I've tried to patch the registerShuffle method of SortShuffleManager, I removed the branch so it will simply return BaseShuffleHandle. I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do that...
  override def registerShuffle[K, V, C](
      shuffleId: Int,
      dependency: ShuffleDependency[K, V, C]): ShuffleHandle = {
    if (SortShuffleWriter.shouldBypassMergeSort(conf, dependency)) {
      // If there are fewer than spark.shuffle.sort.bypassMergeThreshold partitions and we don't
      // need map-side aggregation, then write numPartitions files directly and just concatenate
      // them at the end. This avoids doing serialization and deserialization twice to merge
      // together the spilled files, which would happen with the normal code path. The downside is
      // having multiple files open at a time and thus more memory allocated to buffers.
      new BypassMergeSortShuffleHandle[K, V](
        shuffleId, dependency.asInstanceOf[ShuffleDependency[K, V, V]])
    } else if (SortShuffleManager.canUseSerializedShuffle(dependency)) {
      // Otherwise, try to buffer map outputs in a serialized form, since this is more efficient:
      new SerializedShuffleHandle[K, V](
        shuffleId, dependency.asInstanceOf[ShuffleDependency[K, V, V]])
    } else {
      // Otherwise, buffer map outputs in a deserialized form:
      new BaseShuffleHandle(shuffleId, dependency) 
    }
  }

Changed to:
  override def registerShuffle[K, V, C](
      shuffleId: Int,
      dependency: ShuffleDependency[K, V, C]): ShuffleHandle = {
      
    new BaseShuffleHandle(shuffleId, dependency)
  }

I've tried to run queries on TPC-DS database, I can see in the history server that all the stages finished successfully, but I'm getting wrong output for the query I run.
I run this query (query03 in the TPC-DS queries), dataset size is relatively small (1GB):
  select  dt.d_year 
       ,item.i_brand_id brand_id 
       ,item.i_brand brand
       ,sum(ss_ext_sales_price) sum_agg
 from  date_dim dt 
      ,store_sales
      ,item
 where dt.d_date_sk = store_sales.ss_sold_date_sk
   and store_sales.ss_item_sk = item.i_item_sk
   and item.i_manufact_id = 128
   and dt.d_moy=11
 group by dt.d_year
      ,item.i_brand
      ,item.i_brand_id
 order by dt.d_year
         ,sum_agg desc
         ,brand_id
  limit 100;


I have no idea how to help you, but "getting wrong output" should be elaborated. And with original implementation of registerShuffle(), which shuffle is used? and are you getting the correct output?

The first implementation of registerShuffle that I mentioned is the default one and with this implementation the query result is correct. I think I found the reason for the failure, it's related to the way I bypass the Handler selection, external methods are relying on the SortShuffleManager state and it can cause inconsistencies. I will post an answer to my question that I hope will be clear enough and will help others.

I think I found the cause for the wrong query results, it's related to the way I bypassed the Handler selection.
registerShuffle relies on two methods to decide on which Handler to use, canUseBatchFetch and canUseSerializedShuffle. After taking further look on these methods I've noticed that although they are used only in SortShuffleManager the field MAX_SHUFFLE_OUTPUT_PARTITIONS_FOR_SERIALIZED_MODE is used outside of the SortShuffleManager scope, and one of the instances that relies on this field is ShuffleExchangeExec, in the needToCopyObjectsBeforeShuffle method.
I still checking what this function (needToCopyObjectsBeforeShuffle) do exactly but I've noticed that if I change the value MAX_SHUFFLE_OUTPUT_PARTITIONS_FOR_SERIALIZED_MODE in SortShuffleManager to 0 my patched version produce the right output and uses BaseShuffleHandle like I want.
